# Local SVN repository to git

Tags: linux, svn, git

I am in the need of converting a local SVN repository to GIT.  I know how to convert a remote SVN repository to git, however, I only have the local repositories; they are no longer hosted.  How would I go about converting a local SVN repo to git?

What I tried was this:

`git svn clone -s file://data/svn/repo/ /data/git/repo.git`

Error was:

`E: 'trunk' is not a complete URL  and a separate URL is not specified`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Figured it out...

I needed an extra `/` after `file://` so that it started at the root of the filesystem.  Darn it!

Final command worked:

`git svn clone -s file:///data/svn/repo/ /data/git/repo.git`

Comment: +1 I have experienced the annoyance of that missing slash several times myself.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use [SubGit](http://subgit.com)

```
$ subgit install /data/svn/repo/
```

The difference is that is also converts ignores, tags, EOLs-related settings, and the Git created is automatically kept in sync with the SVN repository. To  break synchronization run

```
$ subgit uninstall /data/svn/repo
```

The resulting repository will br